# Why is rust allowing 2 simultaneous mutable references?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

[The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) says

> "you can have only one mutable reference to a particular piece of data in a particular scope"

As far as I can tell, the following working code contradicts this by having 2 simultaneous mutable references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let r1 = &mut s;
    let r2 = &mut s;
}
```

The code is just a slight modification to this example from the book:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    {
        let r1 = &mut s;
    } // r1 goes out of scope here, so we can make a new reference with no problems.

    let r2 = &mut s;
}
```

The book implies that it's only possible to make the 2nd mutable reference because the first one went out of scope, but when I modified the code so that the first reference does not go out of scope, it still compiles.  Why is this allowed? I thought Rust was only supposed to allow 1 mutable reference at a time.

Comment: I think it's non-lexical scoping of r1 going out of scope.  If you try to actually use r1 after r2, it will error? https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/non-lexical-lifetimes.html

Comment: Non-lexical lifetimes (NLL). Rust compiler can prove that r1 is not used after r2 is taken.

Answer (score 7):

The r1 is still in scope, but you won't be able to use it. That's because it *borrowed* `s`. But once `r2` borrowed it, `r1` is no more use-able.

For example, try adding

```
dbg!(r1);
```

You should get an error:

```
   |
15 |         let r1 = &mut s;
   |                  ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
16 |         let r2 = &mut s;
   |                  ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
17 | 
18 |     dbg!(r1);
   |          -- first borrow later used here
```

Comment: That `dbg!` macro is magical.